# which is the best way to generate choices out of a given set of numbers?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

for example if it is given to make all the choices between 1 to 5 and the answer goes like this..

```
1,2,3,4,5,  
1-2,1-3,1-4,1-5,2-3,2-4,2-5,3-4,3-5,4-5,  
1-2-3,1-2-4,1-2-5,1-3-4,
.....,
1-2-3-4-5.
```

can anyone suggest a fast algorithm?

Comment: ya.. but why a negative vote?? is it not a programming question?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but your question is really vague.  Sure, you've got some kind of "output" written (Why the space runs?  Why the terminating period?) but that could be any language, not just C or C++.  Restricting to those languages implies that you have some desired API (function, class, or template? recursion allowed?) you're not sharing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876474/c-newbie-needs-helps-for-printing-combinations-of-integers  At least look at it for an idea of what a detailed question should contain.

Comment: @mike i placed spaces to make it clear that output size is not restricted to 2 or 3, I need all the possible combos. I m a c++ programmer hence was wishing for a c++ code .. thats it.

Comment: @Kirill: I'd love to see an O(N^2) implementation; there are 2^N combinations to enumerate.

Comment: @Mike Seymour, I just wanted to know at what point OP is now in the question "I need fast algorithm" and that OP understands the problem. Because this question looks like a homework.

Comment: @vaibhav, @Mike Seymour, @Kirill - I think mine is faster than O(2^N), or O(N^2) ;)

Comment: @sje397: that's still O(2^N); the lists are all constructed at run time, and there are 2^N-1 of them. The template just allows the outer loop to be unrolled.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: so now i have to go figure out how to construct the lists with templates? you're so mean :)

Comment: @Mike Seymour: I fixed it. Combinations constructed at compile time. Of course, the printout is still O(2^N).

Comment: possible duplicate of [combinations algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506119/combinations-algorithm)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just generate all the integers from one (or zero if you want to include the empty set) to *2^N - 1*.  Your sets are indicated by the set bits in the number.  For example if you had 5 elements {A,B,C,D,E}  the number 6 = 00110 would represent the subset {C,D}.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the powerset

```
In mathematics, given a set S, the power set (or powerset) of S, written , 
P(S), , is the set of all subsets of S
```

There is an algorithm to find the power set at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms).

```
You basically take first element say 1 and find a all subsets {{},{1}}. Call this 
power set
Take next element 2 and add to powerset and get {{2},{1,2}} and take union
 with powerset.
{{},{1}} U {{2},{1,2}} = {{},{1},{2},{1,2}}
```

But a easy way to do it is described in the answers above. [Here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/power-set.html) is a link which explains it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest is by using [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming), which will trade compile time and code size for execution time. But this will only be practical for lowish numbers of combinations, and you have to know them ahead of time. But, you said "fast" :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int my_uint;

template <my_uint M>
struct ComboPart {
    ComboPart<M-1> rest;

    void print() {
        rest.print();
        for(my_uint i = 0; i < sizeof(my_uint) * 8; i++)
            if(M & (1<<i)) cout << (i + 1) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
};

template <>
struct ComboPart<0> {
    void print() {};
};

template <my_uint N>
struct TwoPow {
    enum {value = 2 * TwoPow<N-1>::value};
};

template <>
struct TwoPow<0> {
    enum {value = 1};
};

template <my_uint N>
struct Combos {
    ComboPart<TwoPow<N>::value - 1> part;
    void print() {
        part.print();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Combos<5> c5 = Combos<5>();
    c5.print();

    return 0;
}
```

This one constructs all the combinations at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called `choose` in combinatorics. [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224024546/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.comb.perm.html) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone suggest a fast algorithm?

Algorithms can be expressed in many languages, here is the power set in Haskell:

```
power [] = [[]]

power (x:xs) = rest ++ map (x:) rest
  where rest = power xs
```

Comment: Or: `power = filterM (const [False,True])`

Answer (score 0):

You want combinations, not permutations (i.e.  {1,2} is the same as {2,1})

C(n,k) = n!/(k!(n-k)!)

Answer = sum(k = 1 to n) C(n,k)

```
      ( i.e. C(n,1)+C(n,2)...+C(n,n) )
```