# Creating all possible k combinations of n items in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, combinations, combinatorics

There are n people numbered from `1` to `n`. I have to write a code which produces and print all different combinations of `k` people from these `n`. Please explain the algorithm used for that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n for a list of algorithms. I don't want to take you the joy of converting them to C++ :)

Comment: Now that it's over, I can say I wrote it in C here https://github.com/olivierpons/interlock-new-challenges/blob/main/include/perms.c

Answer (score 87):

From [Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#C.2B.2B)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
void comb(int N, int K)
{
    std::string bitmask(K, 1); // K leading 1's
    bitmask.resize(N, 0); // N-K trailing 0's
 
    // print integers and permute bitmask
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // [0..N-1] integers
        {
            if (bitmask[i]) std::cout << " " << i;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()));
}
 
int main()
{
    comb(5, 3);
}
```

**output**

```
 0 1 2
 0 1 3
 0 1 4
 0 2 3
 0 2 4
 0 3 4
 1 2 3
 1 2 4
 1 3 4
 2 3 4
```

**Analysis and idea**

The whole point is to play with the binary representation of numbers
for example the number **7** in binary is **0111**

So this binary representation can also be seen as an *assignment list* as such:

For each bit *i* if the bit is set (i.e is **1**) means the **i**th item is assigned else not.

Then by simply computing a list of consecutive binary numbers and exploiting the binary representation (which can be very fast) gives an algorithm to compute all combinations of **N** over **k**.

The **sorting** at the end (of some implementations) is **not needed**. It is just a way to deterministicaly normalize the result, i.e for same numbers (N, K) and same algorithm same *order* of combinations is returned

For further reading about number representations and their relation to combinations, permutations, power sets (and other interesting stuff), have a look at [Combinatorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) , [Factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system)

**PS:** You may want to check out [my combinatorics framework Abacus](https://foo123.github.io/examples/abacus/#action=produce&object=combination&type=default&order=&N=5&K=3&alphabet=&Text=) which computes many types of combinatorial objects efficiently and its routines (originaly in JavaScript) can be adapted easily to many other languages.

Comment: Nikos nice answer, do you think that this can help this question [Generate all sequences of bits within hamming distance t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40813022/generate-all-sequences-of-bits-within-hamming-distance-t)?

Comment: This one is clever. I was looking for solution that reused the standard library functions next_permutation or prev_permutation.  To avoid dynamic memory allocation you can use a std::array of bools instead of a string for the bitset and restrict an upper bound on N.

Comment: I am sure that this answer is brilliant. But, if N == K, ```comb()``` not working. Of course, you can talk that N==K is permutation not combination. But, what I think is that this is not complete solution.

Comment: @TyeolRik, if N==K then there is only one trivial combination, that which includes all items (note we are not talking about variations which is a different combinatorial object). So one can simply test for this trivial case

Comment: @NikosM. Sorry, I just confused the concept between Permutation and Combination due to staying up all night :( You are right. All my mistake.

Answer (score 80):

I assume you're asking about combinations in combinatorial sense (that is, order of elements doesn't matter, so `[1 2 3]` is the same as `[2 1 3]`). The idea is pretty simple then, if you understand induction / recursion: to get all `K`-element combinations, you first pick initial element of a combination out of existing set of people, and then you "concatenate" this initial element with all possible combinations of `K-1` people produced from elements that succeed the initial element.

As an example, let's say we want to take all combinations of 3 people from a set of 5 people. Then all possible combinations of 3 people can be expressed in terms of all possible combinations of 2 people:

```
comb({ 1 2 3 4 5 }, 3) =
{ 1, comb({ 2 3 4 5 }, 2) } and
{ 2, comb({ 3 4 5 }, 2) } and
{ 3, comb({ 4 5 }, 2) }
```

Here's C++ code that implements this idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> people;
vector<int> combination;

void pretty_print(const vector<int>& v) {
  static int count = 0;
  cout << "combination no " << (++count) << ": [ ";
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { cout << v[i] << " "; }
  cout << "] " << endl;
}

void go(int offset, int k) {
  if (k == 0) {
    pretty_print(combination);
    return;
  }
  for (int i = offset; i <= people.size() - k; ++i) {
    combination.push_back(people[i]);
    go(i+1, k-1);
    combination.pop_back();
  }
}

int main() {
  int n = 5, k = 3;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { people.push_back(i+1); }
  go(0, k);

  return 0;
}
```

And here's output for `N = 5, K = 3`:

```
combination no 1:  [ 1 2 3 ] 
combination no 2:  [ 1 2 4 ] 
combination no 3:  [ 1 2 5 ] 
combination no 4:  [ 1 3 4 ] 
combination no 5:  [ 1 3 5 ] 
combination no 6:  [ 1 4 5 ] 
combination no 7:  [ 2 3 4 ] 
combination no 8:  [ 2 3 5 ] 
combination no 9:  [ 2 4 5 ] 
combination no 10: [ 3 4 5 ]
```

Comment: Hi. I'm using your algorithm in an application I'm developing, but I have one problem: in my application, if you have N=6 and k=3, combination(1,2,3) = combination (4,5,6), i.e. picking 1, 2 and 3 is the same as letting 1, 2 and 3 out. Therefore, your algorithm is generating each combination twice, taking twice the time needed to run. I've been trying to cut it half, but I'm having trouble with it. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Edit: I got it. I added a if(offset==0) break; in the end of the for loop.

Comment: I wrote the same algorithm in C here, I hope it will be useful for stone-age people like me: https://github.com/olivierpons/interlock-new-challenges/blob/main/include/perms.c

Answer (score 16):

If the number of the set would be within 32, 64 or a machine native primitive size, then you can do it with a simple bit manipulation.

```
template<typename T>
void combo(const T& c, int k)
{
    int n = c.size();
    int combo = (1 << k) - 1;       // k bit sets
    while (combo < 1<<n) {

        pretty_print(c, combo);

        int x = combo & -combo;
        int y = combo + x;
        int z = (combo & ~y);
        combo = z / x;
        combo >>= 1;
        combo |= y;
    }
}
```

this example calls pretty_print() function by the dictionary order.

For example. You want to have 6C3 and assuming the current 'combo' is 010110.
Obviously the next combo MUST be 011001.
011001 is :
    010000 | 001000 | 000001

010000 : deleted continuously 1s of LSB side.
001000 : set 1 on the next of continuously 1s of LSB side.
000001 : shifted continuously 1s of LSB to the right and remove LSB bit.

```
int x = combo & -combo;
```

this obtains the lowest 1.

```
int y = combo + x;
```

this eliminates continuously 1s of LSB side and set 1 on the next of it (in the above case, 010000 | 001000)

```
int z = (combo & ~y)
```

this gives you the continuously 1s of LSB side (000110).

```
combo = z / x;
combo >> =1;
```

this is for 'shifted continuously 1s of LSB to the right and remove LSB bit'.

So the final job is to OR y to the above.

```
combo |= y;
```

Some simple concrete example :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void pretty_print(const T& c, int combo)
{
    int n = c.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if ((combo >> i) & 1)
            cout << c[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void combo(const T& c, int k)
{
    int n = c.size();
    int combo = (1 << k) - 1;       // k bit sets
    while (combo < 1<<n) {

        pretty_print(c, combo);

        int x = combo & -combo;
        int y = combo + x;
        int z = (combo & ~y);
        combo = z / x;
        combo >>= 1;
        combo |= y;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<char> c0 = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};
    combo(c0, 3);

    vector<char> c1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
    combo(c1, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

result :

```
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 3 4 
2 3 4 
1 2 5 
1 3 5 
2 3 5 
1 4 5 
2 4 5 
3 4 5 
a b c d 
a b c e 
a b d e 
a c d e 
b c d e 
a b c f 
a b d f 
a c d f 
b c d f 
a b e f 
a c e f 
b c e f 
a d e f 
b d e f 
c d e f 
a b c g 
a b d g 
a c d g 
b c d g 
a b e g 
a c e g 
b c e g 
a d e g 
b d e g 
c d e g 
a b f g 
a c f g 
b c f g 
a d f g 
b d f g 
c d f g 
a e f g 
b e f g 
c e f g 
d e f g
```

Comment: This is pure genius! Thank you so much - you have saved me a ton of  time!

Comment: This only works where size of c is less than about 800 with k of 3, not sure why.

Comment: The combo < 1<<n check doesn't work for large n, it's better to calculate the number of combinations and loop until you reach that limit (factorial(n) / (6 * factorial(n - 3))). Also, you may need to use a data type with more bits (unsigned __int128 is best).

Answer (score 8):

In Python, this is implemented as itertools.combinations

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

In C++, such combination function could be implemented based on permutation function.

The basic idea is to use a vector of size n, and set only k item to 1 inside, then all combinations of nchoosek could obtained by collecting the k items in each permutation.
Though it might not be the most efficient way require large space, as combination is usually a very large number. It's better to be implemented as a generator or put working codes into do_sth().

Code sample:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

  int n=5, k=3;

  // vector<vector<int> > combinations;
 vector<int> selected;
 vector<int> selector(n);
 fill(selector.begin(), selector.begin() + k, 1);
 do {
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (selector[i]) {
            selected.push_back(i);
      }
     }
     //     combinations.push_back(selected);
         do_sth(selected);
     copy(selected.begin(), selected.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
     cout << endl;
     selected.clear();
 }
 while (prev_permutation(selector.begin(), selector.end()));

  return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
0 1 2 
0 1 3 
0 1 4 
0 2 3 
0 2 4 
0 3 4 
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 3 4 
2 3 4
```

This solution is actually a duplicate with 
[Generating combinations in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430568/generating-combinations-in-c)

Comment: What is `do_sth`?

Comment: do_sth() is your payload function.

Answer (score 2):

To make it more complete, the following answer covers the case that the data set contains duplicate values. The function is written close to the style of std::next_permutation() so that it is easy to follow up.

```
template< class RandomIt >
bool next_combination(RandomIt first, RandomIt n_first, RandomIt last)
{
  if (first == last || n_first == first || n_first == last)
  {
    return false;
  }

  RandomIt it_left = n_first;
  --it_left;
  RandomIt it_right = n_first;

  bool reset = false;
  while (true)
  {
    auto it = std::upper_bound(it_right, last, *it_left);

    if (it != last)
    {
      std::iter_swap(it_left, it);
      if (reset)
      {
        ++it_left;
        it_right = it;
        ++it_right;
        std::size_t left_len = std::distance(it_left, n_first);
        std::size_t right_len = std::distance(it_right, last);
        if (left_len < right_len)
        {
          std::swap_ranges(it_left, n_first, it_right);
          std::rotate(it_right, it_right+left_len, last);
        }
        else
        {
          std::swap_ranges(it_right, last, it_left);
          std::rotate(it_left, it_left+right_len, n_first);
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      reset = true;
      if (it_left == first)
      {
        break;
      }
      --it_left;
      it_right = n_first;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

The full data set is represented in the range [first, last). The current combination is represented in the range [first, n_first) and the range [n_first, last) holds the complement set of the current combination.

As a combination is irrelevant to its order, [first, n_first) and [n_first, last) are kept in ascending order to avoid duplication.

The algorithm works by increasing the last value A on the left side by swapping with the first value B on the right side that is greater than A. After the swapping, both sides are still ordered. If no such value B exists on the right side, then we start to consider increasing the second last on the left side until all values on the left side are not less than the right side.

An example of drawing 2 elements from a set by the following code:

```
  std::vector<int> seq = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  do
  {
    for (int x : seq)
    {
      std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  } while (next_combination(seq.begin(), seq.begin()+2, seq.end()));
```

gives:

```
1 1 2 2 3 4 5 
1 2 1 2 3 4 5 
1 3 1 2 2 4 5 
1 4 1 2 2 3 5 
1 5 1 2 2 3 4 
2 2 1 1 3 4 5 
2 3 1 1 2 4 5 
2 4 1 1 2 3 5 
2 5 1 1 2 3 4 
3 4 1 1 2 2 5 
3 5 1 1 2 2 4 
4 5 1 1 2 2 3
```

It is trivial to retrieve the first two elements as the combination result if needed.

Answer (score 2):

This templated function works with the vector of any type as an input.
Combinations are returned as a vector of vectors.

```c
/*
* Function return all possible combinations of k elements from N-size inputVector.
* The result is returned as a vector of k-long vectors containing all combinations.
*/
template<typename T> std::vector<std::vector<T>> getAllCombinations(const std::vector<T>& inputVector, int k)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> combinations;
    std::vector<int> selector(inputVector.size());
    std::fill(selector.begin(), selector.begin() + k, 1);

    do {
        std::vector<int> selectedIds;
        std::vector<T> selectedVectorElements;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputVector.size(); i++) {
            if (selector[i]) {
                selectedIds.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        for (auto& id : selectedIds) {
            selectedVectorElements.push_back(inputVector[id]);
        }
        combinations.push_back(selectedVectorElements);
    } while (std::prev_permutation(selector.begin(), selector.end()));

    return combinations;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a class in C# to handle common functions for working with the binomial coefficient, which is the type of problem that your problem falls under.  It performs the following tasks:

1. Outputs all the K-indexes in a nice format for any N choose K to a file.  The K-indexes can be substituted with more descriptive strings or letters.  This method makes solving this type of problem quite trivial.
2. Converts the K-indexes to the proper index of an entry in the sorted binomial coefficient table.  This technique is much faster than older published techniques that rely on iteration.  It does this by using a mathematical property inherent in Pascal's Triangle.  My paper talks about this.  I believe I am the first to discover and publish this technique.
3. Converts the index in a sorted binomial coefficient table to the corresponding K-indexes.  I believe it is also faster than the other solutions.
4. Uses [Mark Dominus](http://blog.plover.com/math/choose.html) method to calculate the binomial coefficient, which is much less likely to overflow and works with larger numbers.
5. The class is written in .NET C# and provides a way to manage the objects related to the problem (if any) by using a generic list.  The constructor of this class takes a bool value called InitTable that when true will create a generic list to hold the objects to be managed.  If this value is false, then it will not create the table.  The table does not need to be created in order to perform the 4 above methods.  Accessor methods are provided to access the table.
6. There is an associated test class which shows how to use the class and its methods.  It has been extensively tested with 2 cases and there are no known bugs.

To read about this class and download the code, see [Tablizing The Binomial Coeffieicent](http://tablizingthebinomialcoeff.wordpress.com/).

It should be pretty straight forward to port the class over to C++.

The solution to your problem involves generating the K-indexes for each N choose K case.  For example:

```
int NumPeople = 10;
int N = TotalColumns;
// Loop thru all the possible groups of combinations.
for (int K = N - 1; K < N; K++)
{
   // Create the bin coeff object required to get all
   // the combos for this N choose K combination.
   BinCoeff<int> BC = new BinCoeff<int>(N, K, false);
   int NumCombos = BinCoeff<int>.GetBinCoeff(N, K);
   int[] KIndexes = new int[K];
   BC.OutputKIndexes(FileName, DispChars, "", " ", 60, false);
   // Loop thru all the combinations for this N choose K case.
   for (int Combo = 0; Combo < NumCombos; Combo++)
   {
      // Get the k-indexes for this combination, which in this case
      // are the indexes to each person in the problem set.
      BC.GetKIndexes(Loop, KIndexes);
      // Do whatever processing that needs to be done with the indicies in KIndexes.
      ...
   }
}
```

The OutputKIndexes method can also be used to output the K-indexes to a file, but it will use a different file for each N choose K case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm i came up with for solving this problem. You should be able to modify it to work with your code.

```
void r_nCr(const unsigned int &startNum, const unsigned int &bitVal, const unsigned int &testNum) // Should be called with arguments (2^r)-1, 2^(r-1), 2^(n-1)
{
    unsigned int n = (startNum - bitVal) << 1;
    n += bitVal ? 1 : 0;

    for (unsigned int i = log2(testNum) + 1; i > 0; i--) // Prints combination as a series of 1s and 0s
        cout << (n >> (i - 1) & 1);
    cout << endl;

    if (!(n & testNum) && n != startNum)
        r_nCr(n, bitVal, testNum);

    if (bitVal && bitVal < testNum)
        r_nCr(startNum, bitVal >> 1, testNum);
}
```

You can see an explanation of how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308438/how-to-cheaply-calculate-all-possible-length-r-combinations-of-n-possible-elem/27308439#27308439).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "count_each_combination" and "for_each_combination" functions from the [combinations library from Howard Hinnant](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/combinations/blob/master/combinations.h) to generate all the combinations for take k from n.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include "combinations.h"

std::vector<std::vector<u_int8_t> >
combinationsNoRepetitionAndOrderDoesNotMatter (long int subsetSize, std::vector<uint8_t> setOfNumbers)
{
  std::vector<std::vector<u_int8_t> > subsets{};
  subsets.reserve (count_each_combination (setOfNumbers.begin (), setOfNumbers.begin () + subsetSize, setOfNumbers.end ()));
  for_each_combination (setOfNumbers.begin (), setOfNumbers.begin () + subsetSize, setOfNumbers.end (), [&subsets] (auto first, auto last) {
    subsets.push_back (std::vector<uint8_t>{ first, last });
    return false;
  });
  return subsets;
}

int main(){
    combinationsNoRepetitionAndOrderDoesNotMatter (6, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36 });
}
```

Benchmark on a Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8600K CPU @ 3.60GHz:
g++

```
benchmark name                       samples       iterations    estimated
                                     mean          low mean      high mean
                                     std dev       low std dev   high std dev
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
combinations no repetition and                                                 
order does not matter 6 from 36                100             1     10.2829 s 
                                        92.5451 ms    92.3971 ms    92.9411 ms 
                                        1.15617 ms    532.604 us    2.48342 ms
```

clang++

```
benchmark name                       samples       iterations    estimated
                                     mean          low mean      high mean
                                     std dev       low std dev   high std dev
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
combinations no repetition and                                                 
order does not matter 6 from 36                100             1     11.0786 s 
                                        88.1275 ms    87.8212 ms    89.3204 ms 
                                        2.82107 ms    400.665 us    6.67526 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Behind the link below is a generic C# answer to this problem: How to format all combinations out of a list of objects. You can limit the results only to the length of k pretty easily.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40417765/2613458

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done using backtracking by maintaining a visited array.

```
void foo(vector<vector<int> > &s,vector<int> &data,int go,int k,vector<int> &vis,int tot)
{

    vis[go]=1;
    data.push_back(go);
    if(data.size()==k)
    {
        s.push_back(data);
        vis[go]=0;
    data.pop_back();
        return;
    }

    for(int i=go+1;i<=tot;++i)
    {
       if(!vis[i])
       {
           foo(s,data,i,k,vis,tot);
       }
    }
    vis[go]=0;
    data.pop_back();
}


vector<vector<int> > Solution::combine(int n, int k) {
   vector<int> data;
   vector<int> vis(n+1,0);
   vector<vector<int> > sol;
   for(int i=1;i<=n;++i)
   {
       for(int i=1;i<=n;++i) vis[i]=0;
   foo(sol,data,i,k,vis,n);
   }
   return sol;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I thought my simple "all possible combination generator" might help someone, i think its a really good example for building something bigger and better*

you can **change N** *(characters)* to any you like by just **removing/adding from string array** *(you can change it to int as well).* **Current amount of characters is 36**

you can also **change K** *(size of the generated combinations)* by just **adding more loops**, for each element, there must be one extra loop. **Current size is 4**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
string num[] = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z" };

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < sizeof(num)/sizeof(string); i1++) {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < sizeof(num)/sizeof(string); i2++) {
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < sizeof(num)/sizeof(string); i3++) {
            for (int i4 = 0; i4 < sizeof(num)/sizeof(string); i4++) {
                cout << num[i1] << num[i2] << num[i3] << num[i4] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

**Result**

```
0: A A A
1: B A A
2: C A A
3: A B A
4: B B A
5: C B A
6: A C A
7: B C A
8: C C A
9: A A B
...
```

**just keep in mind that the amount of combinations can be ridicules.**

--UPDATE--

a better way to generate all possible combinations would be with this code, which can be easily adjusted and configured in the "variables" section of the code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

int main() {
    //VARIABLES
    char chars[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
    int password[4]{0};

    //SIZES OF VERIABLES
    int chars_length = sizeof(chars) / sizeof(char);
    int password_length = sizeof(password) / sizeof(int);

    //CYCKLE TROUGH ALL OF THE COMBINATIONS
    for (int i = 0; i < pow(chars_length, password_length); i++){
       
        //CYCKLE TROUGH ALL OF THE VERIABLES IN ARRAY
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < password_length; i2++) {
            //IF VERIABLE IN "PASSWORD" ARRAY IS THE LAST VERIABLE IN CHAR "CHARS" ARRRAY
            if (password[i2] == chars_length) {
                //THEN INCREMENT THE NEXT VERIABLE IN "PASSWORD" ARRAY
                password[i2 + 1]++;
                //AND RESET THE VERIABLE BACK TO ZERO
                password[i2] = 0;
            }}

        //PRINT OUT FIRST COMBINATION
        std::cout << i << ": ";
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < password_length; i2++) {
            std::cout << chars[password[i2]] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";

        //INCREMENT THE FIRST VERIABLE IN ARRAY
        password[0]++;
    }}
```

Comment: sizeof(string)?

Comment: @ArdentCoder in this context sizeof(num) / sizeof(string) is used to get the number of elements in the array since the array will be the size of how many strings it has multiplied by how big a string is

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of this solution is to mimic the way you enumerate all the combinations without repetitions by hand in high school. Let com be List[int] of length k and nums be List[int] the given n items, where n >= k.
The idea is as follows:

```
for x[0] in nums[0,...,n-1] 
    for x[1] in nums[idx_of_x[0] + 1,..,n-1]
        for x[2] in nums [idx_of_x[1] + 1,...,n-1]
        ..........
            for x[k-1] in nums [idx_of_x[k-2]+1, ..,n-1]
```

Obviously, k and n are variable arguments, which makes it impossible to write explicit multiple nested for-loops. This is where the recursion comes to rescue the issue.
Statement `len(com) + len(nums[i:]) >= k` checks whether the remaining unvisited forward list of items can provide k iitems. By forward, I mean you should not  walk the nums backward for avoiding the repeated combination, which consists of same set of items but in different order. Put it in another way, in these different orders, we can choose the order these items appear in the list by scaning the list forward. More importantly, this test clause internally prunes the recursion tree such that it only contains `n choose k` recursive calls. Hence, the running time is O(`n choose k`).

```py
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def combine(self, n: int, k: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        assert 1 <= n <= 20
        assert 1 <= k <= n
        com_sets = []
        self._combine_recurse(k, list(range(1, n+1)), [], com_sets)
        return com_sets

    def _combine_recurse(self, k: int, nums: List[int], com: List[int], com_set: List[List[int]]):
        """
        O(C_n^k)
        """
        if len(com) < k:
            for i in range(len(nums)):
            # Once again, don't com.append() since com should not be global!
                if len(com) + len(nums[i:]) >= k:
                    self._combine_recurse(k, nums[i+1:], com + [nums[i]], com_set)
        else:
            if len(com) == k:
                com_set.append(com)
                print(com)
```

```
sol = Solution()
sol.combine(5, 3)

[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void combo(vector<char> &alphabet, int n, vector<string> &result, string curr) {
  if (n == 0) {
    result.push_back(curr);
    return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.size(); i++) {
    combo(alphabet, n - 1, result, curr + alphabet[i]);
  }
  return;
}

int main() {
  //N items
  vector<char> alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
  vector<string> result;
  //K is 4
  combo(alphabet, 4, result, ""); 

  
  for (auto s : result) {
    cout << s << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```