# unique permutations over the vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, permutation

I need to take all possible unique combinations of 3 elements in a vector.  `std::next_permutation` works, but it gives me lot of duplicates.

For example

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
and
(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)

first 3 elements that I take are equal, so I'm doing redundant work. Is there any efficient way of iterating through the unique combinations?

Comment: Those two are not 'duplicates'. A permutation includes all elements *by definition*. If you want something that is not really permutations, you have to either look for the correct name of what you want, or describe it more clearly :)

Comment: I think he wants all permutations of the [N over K combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Comment: @ipc Hm, good spot, but I guess he may only want the combinations, not the permutations of the combinations. Let's wait for him to tell us what he actually wants.

Comment: @ipc: Yes. That's right. Thanks for mentioning the right name :) this is very helpful.

Comment: Here is it guys. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991758/creating-all-possible-k-combinations-of-n-items-in-c Thanks very much.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to figure out the number *N* of combinations of *k* objects you can pick out of *b* objects.

### N = b! / (b - k)!

Next you find all the combinations by iterating over your initial list and filling N containers in total with all those combinations.