# Power set generated by bits

Tags: c++, algorithm, subset, powerset, bit-manipulation

I have this code which generates power set of an array of size 4 (number is just example, less combinations to write...).

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 4


unsigned int i, j, bits, i_max = 1U << ARRAY_SIZE;
int array[ARRAY_SIZE];

for (i = 0; i < i_max ; ++i) {
    for (bits = i, j = 0; bits; bits >>= 1, ++j) {
        if (bits & 1)
            printf("%d", array[j]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{}
{1}
{2}
{1, 2}
{3}
{1, 3}
{2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
{4}
{1, 4}
{2, 4}
{1, 2, 4}
{3, 4}
{1, 3, 4}
{2, 3, 4}
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

I need that output to be like this one:

```
{1}
{2}
{3}
{4}
{1, 2}
{1, 3}
{1, 4}
{2, 3}
{2, 4}
{3, 4}
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 4}
{1, 3, 4}
{2, 3, 4}
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

So it has to be ordered like that. I can't do that ordering after that algorithm ends, I have to use every combination in every iteration, so It has to generate that combinations already ordered. Can someone help me out? I think I was thinking about everything...

EDIT: That final output should be without empty set, but it's not priority.

Comment: Did you mean to leave out the empty set in the second case? Mathematically speaking, it is a perfectly valid member of the power set.

Comment: I meant it, just forgot to mention it, sorry. Thx.

Comment: Such an existential question must of course be answered with 42 lines of code (see my answer) ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a version that goes down to the metal with bit-twiddling. It uses a modified version of the famous [Hackers' Delight `snoob()`](http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/snoob.c.txt) function that generates the next greater subset with the **Same Number Of One Bits**. See the [Chess Programming Wiki](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Traversing+Subsets+of+a+Set#Subsets%20with%20equal%20Cardinality-Snoobing%20any%20Sets) (a source of many such bit-twiddling routines).

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using U64 = uint64_t;

// print bit indices of x
void setPrint(U64 x)
{
    std::cout << "{ ";
    for(auto i = 1; x; x >>= 1, ++i)
        if (x & 1) std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << "}\n";
}

// get next greater subset of set with 
// Same Number Of One Bits
U64 snoob (U64 sub, U64 set) {
   U64 tmp = sub-1;
   U64 rip = set & (tmp + (sub & (0-sub)) - set);
   for(sub = (tmp & sub) ^ rip; sub &= sub-1; rip ^= tmp, set ^= tmp)
       tmp = set & (0-set);
   return rip;
}

void generatePowerSet(unsigned n)
{
    auto set = (1ULL << n) - 1;                 // n bits
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n+1; ++i) {
        auto sub = (1ULL << i) - 1;             // i bits
        U64 x = sub; U64 y; 
        do {            
            setPrint(x);
            y = snoob(x, set);                  // get next subset
            x = y;
        } while ((y > sub));
    }
}

int main()
{
    generatePowerSet(4);    
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de929aae2118fa0a) with output in lexicographic order (bonus feature)

```
{ }
{ 1, }
{ 2, }
{ 3, }
{ 4, }
{ 1, 2, }
{ 1, 3, }
{ 2, 3, }
{ 1, 4, }
{ 2, 4, }
{ 3, 4, }
{ 1, 2, 3, }
{ 1, 2, 4, }
{ 1, 3, 4, }
{ 2, 3, 4, }
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, }
```

Comment: Well that's nice solution :)

Comment: tnx, glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to generate all items of a fixed size. Note that the first such item is 1,..,k while the last is (n-k+1),..,n. This is very simple, you basically have to reimplement basic counting: you increment the last "digit", until you reach n. Then you reset to 1 and continue in the same fashion to its left.

Then just have k run from 1 (0) to n.

Here is one proposal for the internal algorithm. It's rather ugly, though.

```
void out(std::vector<int> const& item) {
  char del = '{';
  for (auto it = item.begin(); it != item.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << del << *it;
    del = ',';
  }
  std::cout << "}\n";
}

bool ascending(std::vector<int> const& item) {
  int last = 0;
  for (auto it = item.begin(); it != item.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it <= last)
      return false;
    last = *it;
  }
  return true;
}

void allk(int k, int n) {
  std::vector<int> item;
  item.reserve(k+1);
  for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    item.push_back(i);
  bool valid = true;
  while (valid) {
    out(item);
    do {
      valid = false;
      for (auto it = item.rbegin(); it != item.rend(); ++it) {
        if (*it == n) {
          *it = 1;
        } else {
          ++*it;
          valid = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    } while (valid && !ascending(item));
  }
}
```

Comment: This generates the values if the original set is `{1, ..., n}`. Otherwise, if the original set has `n` elements, this generates `1`-based indexes into that set. (Remember to `-1` if you are using a `0`-based container; very likely in `C++`).

Comment: @BoBTFish: Duplicates are not entirely trivial. I'm thinking about a simple rule to eliminate those.

Answer (score 1):

- I started with a simple recursive permutation generator.
- Added a length parameter and, when the length reaches 0, instead of permuting further, just print the string we have so far.
- Added a position where we must continue picking characters from.

The code:

(I know some people don't like raw arrays / pointers, but it's so much easier to get great performance for this problem with that as opposed to pretty containers)

```
void powerSet(char *arr, int arrLen, int pos, int startPos, int length)
{
   if (length == 0)
      printf("%.*s\n", pos, arr);
   else
      for (int i = startPos; i < arrLen; i++)
      {
         std::swap(arr[pos], arr[i]);
         powerSet(arr, arrLen, pos+1, i+1, length - 1);
         std::swap(arr[pos], arr[i]);
      }
}
```

And the calling function:

```
void powerSet(char *arr, int arrLen)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= arrLen; i++)
      powerSet(arr, 4, 0, 0, i);
}
```

`powerSet("1234", 4)` prints:

```
1
2
3
4
12
13
14
23
24
34
123
124
134
234
1234
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/zASnSo).

Comment: I was thinking of a similar thing first, but OP wants all *sets*, so `AC` = `CA`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a buffer array and then sort it using `qsort` ?

I used a `i_max*5` elements array : 4 `unsigned int` for the values (0 means empty, 1 to 4 otherwise) and **a final unsigned int for the subset length**. Then, you just have to roll with your custom comparator. If you want to a more streamlined algorithm, take a look at insertion sort : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Output:

```
1,
2,
1,2,
3,
1,3,
2,3,
1,2,3,
4,
1,4,
2,4,
1,2,4,
3,4,
1,3,4,
2,3,4,
1,2,3,4,

Sorting
1,
2,
3,
4,
1,2,
1,3,
1,4,
2,3,
2,4,
3,4,
1,2,3,
1,2,4,
1,3,4,
2,3,4,
1,2,3,4,
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int comp (const void * elem1, const void * elem2) {
    unsigned int *f = (unsigned int*)elem1;
    unsigned int *s = (unsigned int*)elem2;
    unsigned int i;


    //printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", f[0],f[1],f[2],f[3],f[4]);
    //printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", s[0],s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4]);
    printf("\n");

    // Size comparison     
    if( f[4] > s[4] ) return 1;
    if( f[4] < s[4] ) return -1;

    // Value comparison
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (f[i] > s[i]) return  1;
        if (f[i] < s[i]) return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int i, j, bits, i_max = (1U << 4);
    unsigned int *array;
    unsigned int index;

    array = calloc( 5*i_max, sizeof(unsigned int));

    // Non-sorted array
    for (i = 0; i < i_max ; ++i) {

        // Zero init for array
        memset(array + i*5, 0, 5*sizeof(*array));
        index = 0;

        for (bits = i, j = 0; bits; bits >>= 1, ++j) {

        if (bits & 1)
            {
                // Storage
                array[i*5 + index]   = j+1;

                index = (index + 1) % 4; // avoid buffer overflows
                array[i*5 + 4]   = array[i*5 + 4] + 1 ; // increment subset length

                //printf("%d,", array[i*5 + index - 1]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Print original array, without the zeros
    for (i =0; i < i_max; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 4 ; j++)
        {
            if( array[i*5 + j] )
                printf("%d,", array[i*5 + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    printf ("Sorting\n");

    qsort (array, i_max, 5*sizeof(unsigned int), comp);


    // Print the sorted array, without the zeros
    for (i =0; i < i_max; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 4 ; j++)
        {
            if( array[i*5 + j] )
                printf("%d,", array[i*5 + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Admirable, but you are missing the empty set `{}`... so technically this does not generate the powerset

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12992511/1870232) answer to make following code:

Basically you need to print `nCr` sequences for all `r`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

 //This generates all nCr sequences
void display(const std::vector<int> & v, 
             std::vector<int>& comb, 
             int offset, int k) {
    if (k == 0) {
        std::cout<<"{";
        for(auto &x:comb)
            std::cout<<x<<",";
         std::cout<<"\b}"<<std::endl;
    return;
    }
    for (int i = offset; i <= v.size() - k; ++i) {
        comb.push_back(v[i]);
        display(v,comb,i+1, k-1);
        comb.pop_back();
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 4;

     std::vector<int> v,comb;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
     v.push_back(i+1); 

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) 
        display(v,comb,0, i);

    return 0;
}
```

See [***here***](http://ideone.com/GNiisP)