# find combinations of numbers stored in an array and store those combinations in another array

Tags: c++, combinations

I have an array of n size and I want to find combinations of k size. I don't just want to print those combinations but want to store those combinations in other arrays or any container. I read this [creating all possible k combinations of n items in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991758/creating-all-possible-k-combinations-of-n-items-in-c) but couldn't succeed in storing the combinations in other arrays. It is because I want to perform operations on those combinations. I'm seeking for any hints regarding this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *How* don't you succeed? Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger to see what happens? And if you haven't done so yet, then I suggest you to please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I can print those combinations but how can I decide the size of the resultant array (which will have the combinations) and should I use arrays or some other containers?

Comment: Why not use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? No need to know the size beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacking a specific reason to choose something else, you probably want to store the results in a vector.

You can pre-compute the number of results quite easily -- N items taken K at a time will produce `N!/K!(N-K)!` total combinations.

At the risk of sounding condescending (which I don't intend) I'll point out that N! grows *very* quickly, so if the difference between N and K is very large, the result may easily be quite a bit larger than most computers can reasonably store.

Comment: Well thanks and let me tell you that it is assumed that the difference between N and K won't be too large.