# greedy algorithm for set cover c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, np-hard

[Minimum Set Cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) is a question where you must find the minimum number of sets needed to cover every element. 
For example, imagine that we have a set of `X=array(1,2,3,4,5,6)` and 5 another set S, where

```
S[1] = array(1, 4)   
S[2] = array(2, 5)   
S[3] = array(3, 6)  
S[4] = array(1, 2, 3)   
S[5] = array(4, 5, 6)
```

The problem is to find minimum number of sets of S which cover every element of X. So obviously the minimum set cover in our case will be `S[4]` and `S[5]` because they cover all the elements.
Does anybody have an idea how to implement this code in C++. Note, that this is NP-complete so there is no fast algorithm to solve it. Any solution in C++ will be welcomed.
And by the way it is not a homework, I need to use this algorithm in [Quine–McCluskey](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FQuine%25E2%2580%2593McCluskey_algorithm&ei=K62qVJ_7Lcn7Uti3g7AL&usg=AFQjCNEkVI8HbSUm65ZSVe7Fk9NHogA6Pg&sig2=NxvXtUa7F_iMbITWfH4gfA&bvm=bv.82001339,d.d24) project in order to generate the last part of solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even though it's not a homework, this is not a code-writing service. The greedy approach is trivial to implement anyway: add sets to result until result contains all elements. Why don't you try this yourself, and ask a question when you have a specific problem?

Comment: What do you want to know? An algorithm or some C++ implementation details/tips? If the latter is the case, which algorithm exactly do you need to implement?

Comment: I just need a c++ code for set covering problem

Comment: @BartoszKP  how can I do this for 2 sets combination it's ok but for more than 2 sets how can I find all 3 sets combination for 4 .....

Comment: @BartoszKP I stuck in finding all 3 set combination and maybe all 4 set combination and so on

Comment: @Jack I think you're not thinking about a greedy algorithm, but about enumerating all possible solutions and finding the best one. That's totally different. But it doesn't change the fact, that this is not a code-writing service. If you're stuck on enumerating combinations, then I'm surprised that you haven't found this (for example!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991758/creating-all-possible-k-combinations-of-n-items-in-c

Comment: @BartoszKP so what is the greedy approach of this question I am confused !!!

Comment: @Jack Please re-read my first comment (the second sentence :) ).

Comment: @BartoszKP but in your way I can just find the result but I want to find the minimum number of sets!!

Comment: @Jack If you want a minimal solution no greedy approach will work (at least I don't think so). This sounds like a case where something like depth-first search would work well.

Comment: @Jack You're right, my explanation of the greedy approach is oversimplified. But it's implementation is just as trivial, you just don't add the sets to the result at random, but choose the sets appropriately (as explained in the Wiki article).

Comment: (but that still won't guarantee an optimal solution, as pointed out by @Omada).

Comment: To sum up: you need to decide whether you want to search the solution space extensively to always find an optimum, or you want the greedy algorithm, which will not always give you an optimal solution. In either case, it's really **too soon to ask a question on SO**.

Comment: Not sure why are you asking for greedy algorithm. Greedy algorithms don't find optimal solution. The take what is best at the current state and only in the current state.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are in a state, where you identified all prime implicancts with the Quine & McCluskey method. Then you have created the prime implicant table and extracted the essential prime implicants. You checked row and columns dominance end eliminated redundant rows and columns. But then you came to an end and have a cyclic core left.

```
     Ac Bc Ab bC aB aC 
  3   X  X
  5         X  X
  7   X     X
  9               X  X
 11      X        X
 13            X     X
```

And now you want to employ the set cover problem to find out all minimum necessary prime implicants.

For this you can use Petrick's method. It is an exact method and will give you a set of minimum results. The implementation is rather simple. 10 lines of code:

```
using MintermSet = std::set<MinTermNumber>;
using Minterm = std::set< BooleanVariable>;
using MintermVector = std::vector<MinTermNumber>;

using MaxtermSet = std::set<MaxTermNumber>;
using ConjunctiveNormalForm = std::set<MaxtermSet>;

using ProductTerm = std::set<BooleanVariable>;
using ProductTermVector = std::vector<ProductTerm>;

// Disjunctive Normal Form
using DNF = std::set<ProductTerm>;
// Conjunctive Normal Form
using CNF = std::vector<DNF>;


class PetricksMethod
{
public:
    // Functors operator
    ProductTermVector operator()(const CNF& cnf);
protected:
};


#include "petrick.hpp"

#include <algorithm>

// Functor operator for applying Petricks methhod

ProductTermVector PetricksMethod::operator ()(const CNF& cnf)
{
    // We select an iterative approach. Start with the first Element of the CNF (which is a DNF)
    // And we sorte the result of each iterative operation again in this element
    DNF resultingDNF{ cnf[0] };
    // We will always start with the element 1 (not element 0) becuase in 0 is the initial value
    // or respectively the intermediate result
    for (CNF::size_type dnfInCnfIndex = 1; dnfInCnfIndex < cnf.size(); ++dnfInCnfIndex)
    {
        // Result of multipliyong out od the intermediate (initial) value with the current CNF Product term
        DNF intermediateCalculatedDNF;
        // Now go through all elements of the intermediate (initial) product term/DNF
        // For (1+2)(3+4)  this would be the (1+2) part
        for (const ProductTerm& productTermLeftSide : resultingDNF)
        {
            // Next we will iterate over all Minterms in the next DNF
            // For (1+2)(3+4)  this would be the (3+4) part
            for (const ProductTerm& productTermRightSide : cnf[dnfInCnfIndex])
            {
                ProductTerm productTerm{ productTermLeftSide }; // Resulting Product term is now 1
                // Add all elements from the right side
                productTerm.insert(productTermRightSide.begin(), productTermRightSide.end());   // Resulting Product term is now 1,2
                intermediateCalculatedDNF.insert(std::move(productTerm));  // Store this one
                // And continue to add more product terms. The stl::set will ensure the idempotence law and prevent memory waste
            }
        }
        // And now add all found terms to the result and continue with the next element of the right hand side
        // Please note: also here the set will prevent double terms
        resultingDNF = std::move(intermediateCalculatedDNF);
    }

    // Now we have the result (with 10 lines of code). The result contains all product terms in DNF
    // But for our prupose we are only interested in the minimum size terms
    // so, lets find the element with the minimu size (can be more than one)
    uint minLength{ narrow_cast<uint>(std::min_element(resultingDNF.begin(), resultingDNF.end(), [](const ProductTerm & left, const ProductTerm & right) noexcept {return left.size() < right.size(); })->size()) };
    // And from the big list of the DNF with all product terms, we copy all elements having the minimu size to the result. These are our best coverage sets
    ProductTermVector cheapestVector;
    // Copy result and return it to caller
    std::copy_if(resultingDNF.begin(), resultingDNF.end(), std::back_inserter(cheapestVector), [&minLength](const ProductTerm& pt) noexcept {return pt.size() == minLength; });
    return cheapestVector;
}
```

All this is part of a software that you can find on [GitHub](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC). You can see also a fully implemented Quine & McCluskey algorithm.

Hope this helps . . .