# k-element combinations binary mask with exclusions

Tags: algorithm, combinations, bitmask

my problem is: for given `n, k` - positive integers and `f` - bitmask `(k <= n, log(f) < n)` find all bitmasks m so that `log(m) < n` and `count_of_ones(m) == k` and `m & f = 0.` For example, if we had a set `S={0,1,2,3,4}`, then solution for `n=5, k=2 and f=0b01010` would represent 2-element combinations of `S-{1,3}`. My current solution is to find masks for `n'=n-count_of_ones(f), k'=k and f'=0` (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43075836/2411220) algorithm) and then 'stretch' them to fit my conditions like this:

```
for(scaled_comb=comb; f > 0; f&=(f-1)) {
    b = f&(-f);
    scaled_comb = ((scaled_comb&~(b-1))<<1)|(scaled_comb&(b-1));
}
```

As You can see, stretching one bitmask takes `O(count_of_ones(f))`. Is there any way to speed it up? Thanks ;)

Comment: Is `n` always an integer?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler (and most likely more efficient, legible, etc...) to just generate them in the obvious manner of recursively building up all masks for the lowest `n` bits?

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on in that stretching code, but it sounds like it could be [`pdep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#Parallel_bit_deposit_and_extract). Is that what it is?

Comment: @Paul yes, n is always integer, updated question. You mean building up masks for lowest `n-count_of_ones(f)` bits? Now I am doing exactly this, but I need to stretch them to fit original conditions, because I use them as keys in hashmap.
@harold yes, this is exactly pdep, thanks ;) unfortunately as far as I see, some cpus (including mine) do not support it (getting 'Illegal instruction: 4' error)

Comment: It can probably be emulated in a more bit-parallel way