# Recursive for-loop for Mastermind algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, algorithm, for-loop, recursion

I want to create a pool of numbers for an Mastermind algorithm (https://www.swtestacademy.com/algorithms-mastermind/). The pool should consist of every possible combination of an Mastermind code with size **n**. So for example when **n = 4** the pool should look like this:

[0000][0001][0002] .... [5555]

with **n = 5**:

[00000] .... [55555]

where every number represents a color from the mastermind solution. So for Example [3101] would be red,blue,white,blue.

I made a function to create a pool with **n = 4**:

```
vector<string> createPool4()
{
    vector<string> pool;

    for (int i = 0; i < colours; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < colours; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < colours; k++)
                for (int l = 0; l < colours; l++)
                    pool.push_back(to_string(i) + to_string(j) + to_string(k) + to_string(l));

    return pool;
}
```

What i tried then, was to transform this function into some kind of recursive nested for-loop but, well look for yourself:

```
vector<string> fillPool(int n, vector<string> pool, const string& s) {

    if (n == 0) {
        pool.push_back(s);
        s.clear();
        return pool;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s += to_string(i);
        pool = fillPool(n-1,pool,s);
    }
}
```

This Code doesn't work, it should just show in what directions I was going.

So to conclude, I need a function that can take a dimension n and then create a list of possible codes. so far i was going with a vector of strings but I'm happy to hear alternative possibilities.

Maybe someone can help me with this, because I know that somewhere out there, there is a really good solution for this.

Thanks!

Comment: You use pool as input and overwrite it with the result ... If this is not optimized in a cool way you have a lot of copies of pool. Maybe it would be better to have a reference to pool to modify.

Comment: I do not see the point to make `s` a const reference. You are modifing the string (by adding another character) so it is not a const reference. I think you should take it by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using combinations and permutations.

The idea is to:

1. create all the possible combinations for a given `n` and `numberOfColours`.
2. create all the different permutations for each combination, append it to the combinations and then remove any duplicates.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991758/creating-all-possible-k-combinations-of-n-items-in-c) has some good answers on how to do the combinations. Putting together this [solution](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations_with_repetitions#C.2B.2B) and this [solution](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#C.2B.2B) from Rosetta code for the combination and permutation respectively, the problem can be solved this way:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void permutation(string str, vector<string> *result) {
  auto strCopy = str;
  std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
  do {
    result->push_back(str);
  } while (std::next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end()));

  // To avoid duplication 
  result->erase(std::remove(result->begin(), result->end(), strCopy), result->end());
}

void combination(int n, int numberOfColours, vector<string> *result) {
  vector<string> colours;
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColours; i++)
    colours.push_back(to_string(i));
  auto s = colours.size() - 1;
  vector<int> v(n + 1, 0);
  while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      if (v[i] > s) {
        v[i + 1] += 1;
        for (int k = i; k >= 0; --k) {
          v[k] = v[i + 1];
        }
      }
    }

    if (v[n] > 0)
      break;
    string str{};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      str.append(colours[v[i]]);
    result->push_back(str);
    v[0] += 1;
  }
}

void createPoolN(int n, int numberOfColours, vector<string> *pool) {
  combination(n, numberOfColours, pool);
  auto perms = make_unique<vector<string>>();
  for (const auto &p : *pool) {
    permutation(p, perms.get());
  }
  pool->insert(pool->end(), perms->begin(), perms->end());
  sort(pool->begin(), pool->end());
}

int main() {
  int n = 5;
  int numberOfColours = 10;
  auto pool = make_unique<vector<string>>();
  createPoolN(n, numberOfColours, pool.get());
  for (const auto &p : *pool)
    cout << "[" << p << "]\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[00000]
[00001]
[00002]
...
[99997]
[99998]
[99999]
```