# Lazy combinations of c++ ranges view

Tags: c++, algorithm, range, c++20

I am looking for an implementation of a ranges view that lazily creates the k combinations of a given range.

For example the range `{1, 2, 3}` with 2 combinations should return:

```
std::vector v {1,2,3};
auto rng = ranges::views::combinations<2>(v);
for(auto[a,b] : rng)
  std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
// 1, 2
// 1, 3
// 2, 3
```

So similar to Pythons `itertools.combinations()` module.

I found the implementations from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991758/creating-all-possible-k-combinations-of-n-items-in-c/28698654). But they are not for ranges and not lazy.

### Solution

My current solution thanks to the answer of this question:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <vector>

// credits to
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n/1617797#1617797
template <typename Iterator>
bool next_combination(const Iterator first, Iterator k, const Iterator last) {
  /* Credits: Mark Nelson http://marknelson.us */
  if ((first == last) || (first == k) || (last == k)) return false;
  Iterator i1 = first;
  Iterator i2 = last;
  ++i1;
  if (last == i1) return false;
  i1 = last;
  --i1;
  i1 = k;
  --i2;
  while (first != i1) {
    if (*--i1 < *i2) {
      Iterator j = k;
      while (!(*i1 < *j)) ++j;
      std::iter_swap(i1, j);
      ++i1;
      ++j;
      i2 = k;
      std::rotate(i1, j, last);
      while (last != j) {
        ++j;
        ++i2;
      }
      std::rotate(k, i2, last);
      return true;
    }
  }
  std::rotate(first, k, last);
  return false;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> values{1, 2, 3, 4};
  auto const comb_size = 3;
  auto lazycombo = [values, comb_size]() mutable {
    bool ok = next_combination(values.begin(), values.begin() + comb_size,
                               values.end());
    return std::span(values.begin(), values.begin() + comb_size);
  };
  auto combinations = ranges::views::generate_n(lazycombo, 3);
  for (auto combination : combinations)
    std::cout << combination[0] << ' ' << combination[1] << ' '
              << combination[2] << '\n';
}
```

[link](https://godbolt.org/z/Gns3r3)

Comment: Does it have to be C++20's ranges? If yes, maybe add a C++20 tag to your question. Else there is also good old [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: ranges-v3 would also be ok!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make "everything" lazy

Totally untested code

```
auto lazycombo = [values, comb_size]() mutable { 
  bool ok = next_combination(values.begin(), values.begin() + comb_size, values.end());
  return std::span(values.begin(), values.begin()+comb_size);
}
```

see [next_combination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1617797/4013258).

Now using your

```
auto combinationIdx = ranges::views::generate(lazycombo);
```

Which should be `generate_n` as there is no way to stop `generate`, where the `n` should be the number of possible combinations.
.

Comment: Crazy method. But it works! Thanks!
I updated my question with a working solution based on your answer. Thank you!