# k-combination of n items with "Gray code"-like property

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, gray-code

I already know how to generate k combinations of n values as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28698654/15853075. The problem is that I need one additional property: I want each pair of successive combinations to differ only at one position (or have "[Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)"-like property). It doesn't matter if it is done during construction or uses a special sorting rule after all combinations are generated.

For example, the original implementation with k=3, n=5 produces the following sequence

```
 0 1 2
 0 1 3 <- good, previous line differs only in the last position (2->3)
 0 1 4
 0 2 3 <- bad, there are two changes (1->2) and (4->3)
 0 2 4
 0 3 4
 1 2 3
 1 2 4
 1 3 4
 2 3 4
```

Instead, I want to see something like this (there can be multiple solutions that satisfy "Gray code"-like property).

```
 0 1 2
 0 1 3 
 0 2 3
 0 2 4
 0 1 4
 0 3 4
 2 3 4
 1 3 4
 1 2 4
 1 2 3
```

It seems that it is possible to keep all numbers inside the combination sorted (`1 0 2` should not occur, only `0 1 2` is allowed).

---

Update

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72096704/15853075) by @Stef shows a solution with the sequence of numbers below. It fails to satisfy the single change property if we consider changes in different columns independently.

```
0, 1, 2
0, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
0, 1, 3 <- bad, change 1: (1->0), change 2: (2->1)
0, 3, 4
1, 3, 4
2, 3, 4
0, 2, 4
1, 2, 4
0, 1, 4
```

The obvious suggestion to reorder the numbers in a combination (to replace `0 1 3` by `1 0 3`) fails to satisfy the sortedness requirement mentioned above.

It is not clear if solution that satisfies this constraint exists for any pair `(n, k)`, but so far I didn't find when it was not possible.

Comment: You will find this interesting: [Gray-code: combinations](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Gray_code#Combinations.2C_partitions.2C_permutations.2C_and_other_objects.)

Answer (score 2):

I found the following recurrence formula to generate the list of combinations in Gray-code order:

```
C(n,k) = C(n-1,k).0 + [C(n-1,k-1)]bar.1
```

Source: [encyclopediaofmaths.org: Gray-code #Combinations](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Gray_code#Combinations.2C_partitions.2C_permutations.2C_and_other_objects.)

With notations explained:

- `C(n,k)` is the list of k-combinations of n elements in Gray-code order;
- `C(n-1,k).0` is just `C(n-1,k)`
- `[L]bar` means "list L in reverse order"
- `L.1` means "the tuples from list L, with n-1 added to each tuple"

With all that in mind, and using python generators, the recurrence formula becomes:

```py
def combinations_graycode(n, k):
    yield from combinations_graycode(n-1, k)
    for comb in reversed(list(combinations_graycode(n-1, k-1))):
        yield comb + (n-1,)
```

Adding a base-case for the recursion, here is the whole python code:

```py
def combinations_graycode(n, k):
    if k < 0:
        raise ValueError('k must be non-negative')
    elif k > n or n < 1:
        pass
    elif k == 0:
        yield ()
    elif k == n:
        yield tuple(range(n))
    else:
        yield from combinations_graycode(n-1, k)
        for comb in reversed(list(combinations_graycode(n-1, k-1))):
            yield comb + (n-1,)

print(list(combinations_graycode(5, 3)))
# [(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3), (0, 3, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 4), (1, 2, 4), (0, 1, 4)]
```

Comment: nice and interesting one ;)

Comment: Nice! I didn't mention this explicitly, but now I am wondering if it is also possible to keep the change at the same position as in my example. In your case `(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3)` has changes in two positions (1->2, 2->3).

Comment: @Curious So does that mean you'd want the code to list the tuples as `(0, 1, 2), (0, 3, 2)` instead of `(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3)`?

Comment: Almost. In addition, I want to keep them sorted. This probably requires a change in the order of concatenation.

Comment: @Curious no, you don't need to change the order. I added a small function to reorder the elements in the tuples, at the end of my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it clearly enough. I meant that (0, 3, 2) should not be allowed because it is unsorted.

Comment: @Curious Oh. In that case, I'm not convinced a solution exists.

Comment: I am also not sure, but for the small cases of `n, k` I always find it by randomly reordering the sequence until it matches all constraints.