# Algorithm loop combination

Tags: c++, loops, combinations

I have 10 text files containing one column of 1,-1,0.
I want to set a combination which sum the elements of each file.

For example, if I want to see all the combinations of 2 files among 10 files, I would create the 2 loops below:
double sum;

```
for(int i;i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j;j=i;j<n;j++){
        sum += x[i]+x[j];
    }
}
```

Another example, if I want to see all the combinations of 3 files among 10 files, I would create the 3 loops below:

```
for(int i;i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j;j=i;j<n;j++){
        for(int k;k=j;k<n;k++)
           sum += x[i]+x[j]+x[k];
        }
    }
}
```

and so on, if I want to see the combinations x files among 10 files, I would create x loops.

My question is: I am looking for an algorithm which determines the number of loops by choosing x. If x=2, then I create 2 loops, if x=3, then I create 3 loops, if x=4, then I create 4 loops, ... or may be there is another way. 
Many thanks

Comment: And if you had 50 files, 50 nested loops??  That's insane.  Needless to say, there are better ways, such as using `std::next_permutation` along with some logic to generate combinations (there are **many** examples here on SO) where you need one (or two) loops, regardless of the number of items.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `std::next_permutation` looks not very useful here since the TS needs combinations, not permutations

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 -- You're mistaken.  You can use a `std::next_permutation` to produce combinations if you put [some effort into it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430568/generating-combinations-in-c).  The trick is to use a control array that consists of boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the code you provided really works as `for (int i;i=0;i<n;++i)` most likely has to be `for (int i=0;i<n;++i)`. Though that aside, you are searching for some kind of recursion.

Let me assume you have stored this data in an `std::vector`, than I would recommend creating a 2D variant `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Having recursion requires 2 elements: the stop condition and the recursing:

```
void function(int &sum, const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &data, std::size_t outerLevel, std::size_t innerLevel, int intermediate) {
    // Stop condition of recursion,
    // if we don't have any elements any more,
    // the intermediate is our final result.
    if (outerLevel == data.size()) {
        sum += intermediate;
        return;
    }

    // Recursing
    const std::vector<int> &subData = data[outerLevel];
    for (auto i = innerLevel; i < subData.size(); ++i) {
        function(sum,
                 data,
                 outerLevel+1, // Go to the next std::vector<int>
                 i,            // Make sure the next inner loop starts at the right index
                 intermedite+subData[i] // Take the intermidiate sum
                 );
    }
}

// Wrapper to hide itermediate calculation variables
int functionWrapper(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &data) {
    int sum = 0;
    function(sum, data, 0, 0, 0);
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compute the sum, it is even simple as

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
        sum += x[i] + x[j];
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum += (n - i) * x[i];
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
        sum += x[j];
    }
}
```

and with some more effort

```
sum += (n + 1) * std::accumulate(std::begin(x), std::end(x), 0);
```

and for 3

```
const int sumx = std::accumulate(std::begin(x), std::end(x), 0);
sum += ((n + 1) * (n + 2) / 2) * sumx;
```

Comment: I would like to thank you all of you who have answered so quickly to my question. I will study the answers and will come back with a code if I understand. I have to say I need to spend some time on it to make sure I understand the algorithm. First, I will study PaulMcKenzie