# Test every combination of functions in every order

Tags: c++, function, permutation

I have a bunch of functions, `a.process`, `b.process`, `c.process`..., let's call them `a`, `b`, `c`... that all take a `std::string` as parameter and return a `std::string`.

Given an initial `std::string s`, I want to generate every possible output of combinations of `a`, `b`, `c`... called in any order and given `s` as initial input.

So for instance, I want to calculate `a(s)`, `b(s)`, `c(s)`, `a(b(s))`, `a(c(s))`, `b(a(s))`, `b(c(s))`, `c(a(s))`, `c(b(s))`, `a(b(c(s)))`, etc.

I think I could do a function to generate every permutation of a list, something like Python's `itertools.permutations` but I have two main issues here:

- I don't just want every permutation, I want every permutation in every order.
- And more important, I have no idea about how to store functions in arrays like one would easily do in Python.

Also I need that each possible output comes with the combinations of functions that generated it so for the example I gave above, I would know that outputs are in the following order: `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, `"ab"`, `"ac"`, `"ba"`, `"bc"`, `"ca"`, `"cb"`, `"abc"`, etc.

How could I implement that in C++?

Answer (score 1):

For storing functions in an array, you need to use [function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html). Something like this would do:

```
typedef string (*t_fnPtr)(string);
t_fnPtr fnPtrArray[10]; //Initialize this with your functions
```

Then it's just a matter of generating all combinations of your array and applying it to the string. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430568/generating-combinations-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

I'm just fleshing out [Sid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44479387/4832499) into actual code. Differing from [Galik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44480496/4832499), this doesn't produce duplicates

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using Fn = std::string (*)(std::string);

std::string apply_all(const std::vector<Fn>& fns, std::string s)
{
    for(auto fn : fns)
        s = fn(s);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = /* some string */;
    std::vector<Fn> functions{/* initialize with functions */};
    int n = functions.size();

    for(int r = 1; r <= n; r++)
    {
        std::vector<bool> v(n);
        std::fill(v.begin(), v.begin() + r, true);  // select r functions

        // permute through all possible selections of r functions
        do {
            std::vector<Fn> selected;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                if(v[i])
                    selected.push_back(functions[i]);

            std::sort(selected.begin(), selected.end());

            // permute through the r functions
            do {
                std::cout << apply_all(selected, s) << std::endl;
            } while(std::next_permutation(selected.begin(), selected.end()));
        } while(std::prev_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://cpp.sh/9d62v)

Comment: How should I do it if my functions are extracted from instances? I cannot initialize the vector of functions with `{class1.a, class2.a, class3.a}` for example, but I cannot use `CLASS1::a` because my functions vary depending on instance initialization.

Comment: Change `Fn` to `std::function<std::string (std::string)>`, and initialize with `[&](std::string s){return class1.a(s);}`. [More on lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas and pseudocode

Array of function pointers, one for each function.

```
typedef std::string (*Func)(std::string const&);
Func const func_array[] = {&a, &b, &c};
int const n = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];  // number of functions
```

We need

```
 n choose 1 to get 1-element combinations a, b, c
 n choose 2 to get 2-element combinations ab, ac, bc
 n choose 3 to get 3-element combinations abc
```

Further, for each combination, we need all possible permutations. I.e.

```
 For all k = 1 to n, 
   All permutations of (All combinations of n-choose-k)
```

Sketch

```
for i = 0 to 2^(n-1):
  xi = elements of func_array corresponding to the '1' bits in i
    used std::next_permutation() to generate all permutations of xi
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the problem right maybe something like this. It uses `std::next_permutation` to iterate through every ordering of processes and for every ordering it selects each sub-list or processes to operate (successively) on the input:

```
std::string process_1(std::string const& s)
    { return s + 'a'; }

std::string process_2(std::string const& s)
    { return s + 'b'; }

std::string process_3(std::string const& s)
    { return s + 'c'; }

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    using process = std::string(*)(std::string const&);


    std::vector<process> processes;

    processes.push_back(process_1);
    processes.push_back(process_2);
    processes.push_back(process_3);

    std::vector<std::string> outputs;

    std::sort(std::begin(processes), std::end(processes));

    do
    {
        for(auto p = std::begin(processes); p != std::end(processes); ++p)
        {
            std::string s = "";
            for(auto p1 = p; p1 != std::end(processes); ++p1)
                s = (*p1)(s);

            outputs.push_back(s);
        }
    }
    while(std::next_permutation(std::begin(processes), std::end(processes)));

    for(auto const& o: outputs)
        std::cout << o << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
abc
bc
c
acb
cb
b
bac
ac
c
bca
ca
a
cab
ab
b
cba
ba
a
```

**NOTE:** It seems this method produces some duplicates. There should be a clever mathematical way to eliminate them that eludes me right now but you can always maintain a `std::set<std::vector<process>>` to record every combination that has already been tried to make sure there are no repeats. Or simply remove duplicates from the output.