# C++ generating different permutations of a list?

Tags: c++

Hi I am doing an assignment for C++ and my teacher unfortunately can't teach me anything about C++ so I have to resort to the internet to help me out.

I'd appreciate a simple, easy way to output all of the permutations of a list, for example, if list x has 3 different values of [1,2,3], output=[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1] etc... the list does not necessarily have to be in that order, just needs to output all of the different combinations of 1, 2, 3 in a list. that's all. 
I've looked online to figure out how to do this with no luck understanding much. I've seen people use vectors for this and a bunch of other things that I have about 0% understanding of. I'd love to just copy and paste others' codes but that won't help get anywhere for this class, or anywhere with C++ since I am the only one voluntarily learning this language. So please try to explain it in layman's terms as much as possible. I am using C++11 if that helps.

This is about as far as I got myself

```
std::cout << "\nPart 2: Enter a list of 3 numbers, press enter after each value: \n";
std::list<int> mylist1;
int v1;
int v2;
int v3;
std::cin >> v1 >> v2 >> v3; //input that will go into the list
mylist1.push_front(v1);
mylist1.push_back(v2);
mylist1.push_back(v3);
```

Comment: All you have done is push some integral values into a list.    You've shown no effort at generating combinations of those values.    This isn't a "tell me how to do this because I haven't worked out how" forum.   You tend to be rewarded if you show an effort, and run into some specific problem.  You haven't done that, so voting to close.

Comment: [std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).  Enough said.

Comment: Be aware that combinations are not the same as permutations. You are looking for permutations. +1 for @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @Peter calm down im genuinely just trying to learn the language, i thought this community will help but apparently few people will... i cant put effort into a language i have little to no understanding of, it's like making a student do a presentation in a foreign language they know nothing about.

Comment: @KrutikShah - people here tend to help people who demonstrate some effort to solve their problem, and have run into some difficulty in that..   You haven't shown any effort to generate permutations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating combinations in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430568/generating-combinations-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a function for that, it's called [`next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void show(const std::vector<int> &vtr) {
    for (auto val : vtr)  std::cout << val << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{ 12,1,6,4,0 };
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    show(vec);
    while (std::next_permutation(vec.begin(), vec.end())) {
        show(vec);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is a vector? I'm sorry im new to C++, i have no idea what any of your code means

Comment: @KrutikShah You are already using `std::list` but not know what `std::vector` is??  The first container you should have encountered is `std::vector`.  Who taught you `std::list` before `std::vector`?

Comment: Krutik, a vector is somewhat like a list, but implemented differently. It is all in one chunk, rather than being linked together. You are not going to be able to learn C++ by asking questions on StackOverflow. (@PaulMcKenzie)

Comment: If you want to know what the code "means", try running it. It is a complete answer to your question.

Comment: alright I'll try this out. seems like I'll have to do some more research on vectors and lists after this, but I have a general understanding, thanks.

Comment: @KrutikShah One of my favourite go-to places is http://en.cppreference.com it has documentation on just about everything complete with usage examples. For example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @user4581301 alright thanks, looks quite useful

Comment: @KrutikShah *i looked up how to create a list and i went from there* -- Doing things this way is not a good method to learn C++ properly.   Every good C++ book or tutorial introduces `std::vector` first.  The `std::list` is basically second-tier or even third-tier.  So the question is how you came across `std::list`, when it is basically a container that is not often used.  Is it that you come from Java or another language where "List" means something, so you looked up `std::list`?  If so, this is the danger of leveraging what you learned from one language and attempting to learn C++ this way.