# How to generate variations from a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, permutation

Is there an easy way in C++17 to generate variations from a given vector of elements?

```
void get_variations(int len, const std::vector<int> &array, std::vector<std::vector<int>> &result) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;
    std::vector<int> array = {1, 2, 3};

    get_variations(2, array, result);

    for(auto variation : result) {
        for(auto element : variation) {
            std::cout << element << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output should be:

```
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 3
3 1
3 2
```

Comment: Do you mean "permutations"? Maybe you want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430568/generating-combinations-in-c

Comment: I do not mean combinations. In variations the order of elements in result is important - in combinations not. 4 2 1 is not 2 1 4.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "permutations", comment edited.

Comment: Please show the complete desired output for `{1,2,3}` and for `{1,2}`

Comment: Correct. Permutations of specific length.